# PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007 Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Tags: php, laravel

**Version:**

`composer.json` :

```
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.0.1",
        "ext-zip": "*",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.25",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.6",
        "laravel/ui": "^3.2",
        "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.16"
```

---

**Problem:**

> ErrorException
> Trying to access array offset on value of type null

---

After upgrading to Laravel 8 and PHP 8. I'm getting above error.

```
<?php

use PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007;


$objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007();
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load('/path/to/filename.xlsx'); // This line
```

Comment: That line you've highlighted doesn't try to access an array. Is there a stack trace? I'd guess the root cause is somewhere inside the library.

Comment: @ADyson Can I do something in `phpspreadsheet` instead of `PHPExcel` here.

Comment: If you're using PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007 instead of phpspreadsheet, you may want to switch. PHPExcel is abandoned and may not work with PHP8. I'm not familiar with either package, so couldn't tell you how to switch.

Comment: `Can I do something in phpspreadsheet` ... I don't know. Your example simply opens a file. I've no idea what you're going to want to do after that. Try it and see if it meets your needs.

Comment: Actually, if you go to https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel it specifically tells you not to use PHPExcel anymore, and to use phpspreadsheet instead. So yeah it looks like you should be upgrading. Read https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/blob/master/docs/topics/migration-from-PHPExcel.md as well.

Answer (score 2):

Find the line of the error at the library file, in my case was some array that should not be null $attributes[$t] I've change it.

```
if ($attributes['t'] == 'array') { //from this
if (isset($attributes['t']) && $attributes['t'] == 'array') { //to this
```

the error dissapeared.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that the file is missing some property, what i did and that worked is i have the file with libreOffliceCal and i did a ctrl + s to save and when i tried again i no longer had this mistake

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by replacing line 1688 in /PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel2007.php

Main:

```
$activeTab = intval($xmlWorkbook->bookViews->workbookView["activeTab"]);
```

Replaced:

```
 $activeTab =isset($xmlWorkbook->bookViews->workbookView["activeTab"])? intval($xmlWorkbook->bookViews->workbookView["activeTab"]):"sheet1";
```